# Get selected option server side

Tags: c#, javascript, client-side, html-select

I'm getting a list of values on server side and I'm creating a dropdownlist with this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<select name=\"topics\" class=\"topicsSelect\" id=\"topicsSelect\">");
foreach (var topic in sorted){
sb.AppendFormat("<option value='{0}'>1{1}</option>", LinkManager.GetItemUrl(topic),
                                (topic.Fields["PageTitle"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic.Fields["PageTitle"].Value))
                                    ? topic.Fields["PageTitle"].Value
                                    : topic.Name);
            }

            sb.Append("</select>");
            litTopicList.Text = sb.ToString();
```

But now I'm trying to get the selected value onclick and I can't access this information?
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
string topicsSelect = Page.Request.Form["topicsSelect"];
```

or just

```
string topicsSelect = Page.Request["topicsSelect"];
```

Comment: Tks Claudio, I've tried and I'm getting null for both suggestions. Any other idea?

Comment: This would need to refer to the element by *name* and not *id* wouldn't it? @Snapper Try replacing "topicsSelect" with "topics" in the above examples.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the example here?

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Hi bilgibilism... I'm trying to get the value on the server side... I have to redirect to other page based on the selected value but not only  protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var url = Utilities.GetXMLSetting(Utilities.SettingType.ITEM, "item");} and then add to the url the selected value

Comment: Hi,

This line is wrong, because html controls is required in html dom object.


litTopicList.Text = sb.ToString();

sb.ToString() write to in body element.

Try the code in the answer above